# Show chapter markers on the timeline in HTML5 video?

Tags: html, video, timeline, video.js

How do I show Chapter Markers on the timeline in Video.js? [Or any other player, for that matter]

Take a look here:
laurencemoroney.azurewebsites.net/smf/videojstest.html

I added a WebVTT file to the site, visible here:
laurencemoroney.azurewebsites.net/smf/test1.vtt

I used the  tag on my player, like this:

```
<track kind="chapters" src="test1.vtt" srclang="en" label="English" default="default"></track>
```

The best result I can get is on Safari, where I just get the Chapter name displayed when the video hits that point on the timeline.

So, is there a way (or a skin) for Video.js, that shows me notches on the timeline for chapters, and which allows me to click on them to jump to that chapter?

Or, alternatively is there another player that supports this?

Comment: have you spoken to the Media Player Framework folks (in DPE) - http://playerframework.codeplex.com/

Comment: I did...and their timeline markers have bugs in Android, so I'm looking at other options...

Comment: I've not found a good, lightweight solution that works everywhere (the pre-Chrome experience on Android is horrible and WP7 isn't that nice). Would love to know if you find one (or contribute a fix to PF!)

Comment: I spoke with Mike...but video.js *should* work, or there should be a skin for it somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Plyr.io](https://plyr.io/).

It supports chapter [markers](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#:%7E:text=markers) (clickable visual indicators which can also have a tooltip image) and works pretty well cross platform